# Implementing an iterator for a immutable data type

Tags: java, iterator, immutability

For my current university course we are required to implement an Iterator for an immutable data type. So far so good, nothing too dificult, here is what it looks like:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator(){
    return new Iterator<T>() {
        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            //hasNext implementation
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            //Next Implementation
        }
    };
```

I used a mutable variable (index) that points to the current position in the data type. The exercise requires us to make every member variable final (makes sense for an immutable data type), but it also requires us to make every member variable in the iterator final (index). This is what makes me confused, because I dont see a way of iterating over a data type without a mutable variable, especially because you cant change the iterator from inside of the next() method...
I dont want a solution to the problem, I just want to know, wether or not this is possible and maybe a slight hint to a solution... Thanks!

Comment: "make every member variable final (makes sense for an immutable data type)" Iterators aren't meant to be immutable data types. How do you know you're meant to make `index` final? Have you been told to, or are you assuming that you need to?

Comment: `index` shouldn't be final. But a possible workaround would be to create a `final` array of just one position.

Comment: Yes we were told to make every member of the Iterator final... I dont know were the exercise is going with this restriction, It doesnt make sense to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If making every member variable `final` is your requirement, you *could* make `index` into an array:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator(){
    return new Iterator<T>() {
      private final int[] index = {0};
      // ...
    };
}
```

because array elements remain are mutable, even if the reference to it is `final`. But this just makes the code messier, because of using `index[0]` everywhere instead of just `index`.

Iterators are inherently mutable; there's no way I can think of to make them immutable, since you *want* them to change as you use them.

---

Note that simply making all member variables `final` does make a type immutable. The member variables must also refer to deeply-immutable objects; non-zero length arrays cannot be deeply immutable, since you can always reassign their elements.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm not very familiar with Java, and am basing this off what I would do in C#, but I'll have a go.*

*Note: I'm disregarding the 'hints only' request as it's now much later, so I'm assuming that that's no longer relevant. Otherwise, don't read beyond the first code sample (inclusive or exclusive, up to you).*

You could solve this by making an iterator type that returns a new iterator object each time you move to the next element. So, essentially, each move-next operation would return three things:

- Whether there is a next item (as usual)
- What the next item is (as usual)
- A new iterator object that represents the next item (i.e. a copy of the current iterator, but moved forward one element).

The advantage of this design is that you can stop iteration at any point, and resume from that point later - without having to first iterate through the prior elements of the collection. With .NET LINQ methods such as Where() or OrderBy(), which could require a lot of processing to iterate through the prior elements again, this could be very beneficial in some situations.

However, this new pattern would not support in-built features (such as Java equivalents of foreach and LINQ). Additionally, the iterator object should probably be a value type to improve performance (as a new instance is created for every item in the collection), however Java does not support custom value types. The Java pattern could therefore look something like:

```
interface IterationItem<T> {
    public T getValue();
    public boolean hasNext();
    public IterationItem<T> next();
}
```

With an implementation looking like:

```
class ListIterationItem<T> implements IterationItem<T>
{
    private List<T> _list; // Could be public (so long as it's read-only)
    private int _index;    // ^
    private T _value;

    public ListIterationItem(List<T> list, int index) {
        _list = list;
        _index = index;
        _value = list[index];
    }

    public T getValue() { return _value; } //Or look up the value on-demand, idk which is better

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return _index + 1 < _list.size())
    }

    public IterationItem<T> next() {
        return new ListIterationItem<T>(_list, _index + 1);
    }
}
```

You can use this like so:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
IterationItem<String> item = new ListIterationItem<String>(list, 0);
while (true) {
    String current = item.getValue();

    //Do something with the current value

    if (item.hasNext()) { item = item.next(); }
};
```

Or, if you really needed to avoid modifying any fields (eg. when using a language that doesn't allow you to), you could use recursion:

```
void Main() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    ProcessElements(new ListIterationItem<String>(list, 0));
}
void ProcessElements(IterationItem<T> item) {
    String current = item.getValue();
    //Do something with the current value
    if (item.hasNext()) {
        ProcessElements(item.next());
    }
}
```

You could also write a method to wrap any iterator of this kind as a normal iterator, so that it can be used in for-each loops and so on:

```
public static Iterable<T> AsIterable<T>(IterationItem<T> item)
    return new Iterable<T>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<String>() {
                private IterationItem<T> currentItem = item; //Idk if this works

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return item.hasNext();
                }

                @Override
                public String next() {
                    item = item.next();
                    return item.getValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

I arrived here having thought of this idea, and then having decided to research it - but this is the most relevant page I've found so far, so I thought I'd write down what I've thought of. If anyone knows of anything similar, I'd be interested to know.